# How do I remove a specific value from a string of comma separated values?

Tags: excel, vba, string, excel-formula, substitution

I have two columns. Column A with a single value and Column B with a string of comma-separated values.

I want to find the value in Column A in the string of values in Column B and remove it. Leaving the remainder of the values separated by the commas.

For example:

[image]

The SUBSTITUTE formula ive been playing with is `=SUBSTITUTE(B2,A2," ")`

One issue that I'm running into is some of the values have the "/" character in them which I wish to keep.

*Example:*

**Column A**

FC0201F1I

**Column B**

FC0201F1I,FC0201F1I/FC0201F2I,FC0201F2I

**SUBSTITUTE output ruins the Value:**

, /FC0201F2I,FC0201F2I

**The output I'm looking for:**

FC0201F1I/FC0201F2I,FC0201F2I

Any Excel Formula combination or VBA Code to help me in this mystery would be greatly appreciated. I feel the solution is so simple and staring at me in the face but I am unable to see it.

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 4):

Add commas to the beginning and end to both strings inside the SUBSTITUTE then use spaces and trim to remove the `,` if they are added to the front or back and not replaced:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(","&B2&",",","&A2&",",""),","," "))," ",",")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this is possible through some xpath in `FILTERXML()`:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTERXML("<t>"&A1&"<s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.!=../text()]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do 2 substitutions, 1 for the search term followed by a column and 1 for the search term preceded by a comma.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,","&A2, ""), B2&",","")
```

Comment: The inner substitute `SUBSTITUTE(B2,","&A2, "")` will return `/FC0201F2I,FC0201F2I` to the outer as already incorrect.

Comment: It actually won't but the only reason for that is because the text being searched begins with the search term. My formula is wrong though.:)